# Custom Controller code for Strapi Beta (3.0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, strapi

I have some code from the previous version of Strapi that works, and the beta version of controllers is much different. There is multipart / santization boilerplate added and something has changed.  Do not understand how to integrate my order object and stripe charge.

Here is the boilerplate added:

```
  module.exports = {
       async create(ctx) {


 // New Boilerplate added with Strapi Beta - how to integrate this with custom stuff below? 
 let entity;
   if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
     const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
     entity = await service.create(data, { files });
   } else {
     entity = await service.create(ctx.request.body);
   }
return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model });
 }
  }
```

Here is my custom code  (The controller name is Order.js)

```
 const { address, amount, products, postalCode, token, city } = ctx.request.body;

 // Send charge to Stripe
 const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
   amount: amount * 100,
   currency: 'usd',
   description: `Order ${new Date(Date.now())} - User ${ctx.state.user.id}`,
   source: token
 });

 // Create order in database
 const order = await strapi.services.order.add({
   user: ctx.state.user.id,
   address,
   amount,
   products,
   postalCode,
   city
 });
```

It looks like I would add my code to the second part of the if statement since it's not multipart, but not user if "entity" is a real variable name Strapi needs or a placeholder variable I rename to "order"  Code works fine in Alpha, but read the Strapi docs and there is no explanation to how to use this structure with "entity", {model} and "data" variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the previous version of Strapi, to upload a file to a new entry you had to first, create your entry and two, upload the image and specify the entry you want to link this image.
Now with the multipart, you can send your image at the same time as your entry attributes.

Now about your use-case, `service.` has to be replaced by `strapi.api.order.service.order` in your case.
I agree the doc is not clear! I will update that right now.

```
const { parseMultipartData, sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async create(ctx) {
    // New Boilerplate added with Strapi Beta - how to integrate this with custom stuff below?
    let entity;
    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      entity = await strapi.api.order.services.order.create(data, { files });
    } else {
      const { address, amount, products, postalCode, token, city } = ctx.request.body;

      // Send charge to Stripe
      const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: amount * 100,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: `Order ${new Date(Date.now())} - User ${ctx.state.user.id}`,
        source: token
      });

      entity = await strapi.api.order.services.order.create({
        user: ctx.state.user,
        address,
        amount,
        products,
        postalCode,
        city
      });
    }
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.query('order').model });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  One other question is that it throws a 500 and can't get this value: ctx.state.user.id  It says not found.  Has Strapi changed the way we also get values?

Comment: New problem: TypeError: strapi.api.order.services.create is not a function

Comment: If I just remove .id just to do testing, it gets past the first instance with just ctx.state.user, but then fails saying that strapi.api.order.services.create is not a function, so I can't seem to get the id anymore.

Comment: Arg I missed `strapi.api.order.services.order.create`.

Comment: thanks Jim.  Would have never arrived to that conclusion without your help.  it works now, but I have to remove 'id' from both assignments....on the create for user, I have to change it to user: ctx.state.user, and leave off .id for some reason?

Comment: Okay I updated my message. In fact when you create a relation (in this case with user) you can link the entry object or just its ID. So normally it should work with `.id`.
I will investigate to know why it failed with `.id`.
Can you also validate the question as resolved by this message? Like this, it will help me in the question management. Thank you for your feedback on this `.id` topic.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  Yes, the solution proposed works and the credit card transaction goes through.  Works fine...BUT only without .id   Hope this helps in troubleshooting.  It just returns as undefined when .id is attached as a property of the object.

Comment: Hey Jim, any thoughts on this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560598/strapi-beta-with-custom-sendgrid-controller-code-for-email